# Execute fastboot commands without PC

Tags: fastboot, twrp

I have setup adb server and client within the Android device and can issue adb commands via terminal emulator.

But I need to have the fastboot in the same way. My requirement is to temporarily boot into TWRP without a PC or another Android device:

```
# fastboot boot /path/to/twrp.img
```

I think the Android has fastboot-over-usb.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute fastboot commanda without a physical connection to the phone.

Fastboot is another name for "bootloader mode", where the bootloader stops itself before further loading the OS, and waits for fastboot commands.

Since bootloader is very simple, your only bet would be connecting your phone to a computer.

Comment: Does the fastboot-over-usb means the fastboot still can be accessed after booting into Android?

Comment: @Seff I'm afraid no. After booting into Android, there's no more "fastboot" mode.

Comment: Fastboot is only active while *in* bootloader mode. Think of the bootloader like a "GUI-less boot menu": device enters bootloader, bootloader decides how to continue by indicators given such as hotkeys hold (boot to recovery?) or specific flags existing (not sure which, but that's what must be the case when eg. having run `adb reboot bootloader`). Once that decision has been made, bootloader hands over the process to the next instance and exits. See [Can somebody explain the boot process of an Android device?](/q/29706/16575) (step 2 in my answer there) for details.